getElapsedTime always returns 0 in the removal code section of a Delay block
I wanted to see how long agents I am removing from a Delay block named delayX has waited, so I called delayX.getElapsedTime(agent) in the “on removal” code section of delayX. However, this function always returned 0, even for agents that I knew had waited for some time in the block. Can anyone give any pointers on where I went wrong?

PS: Sufficient  to only use the "anylogic" tag, no other tags necessary :)

I suspect getElapsedTime() only works when not manually removing agents from Delay.
However, you can easily use this call to compute the time in the Delay block upon removal:
double durInDelay = time()-agent.getFlowchartEntryTime().
This will work.
